# How to highlight certain portion of an image?

Tags: r, image-processing

I am trying to process a tissue image in R and I have been able to highlight certain cells with black color and rest background is white in color. My question is very similar to this (being a newbie I am unable to post picture)

[How to circle/highlight/rectangle certain regions of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778166/how-to-circle-highlight-rectangle-certain-regions-of-an-image)

Just that I need to know how will this be possible in R. I have tried many functions and searched for many techniques but no result yet. Here is the code and the original image

```
img<-readJPEG("img.jpg")
img<-array(img,c(480,640,3))

imgDm <- dim(img)



imgRGB <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:imgDm[2], each = imgDm[1]),
  y = rep(imgDm[1]:1, imgDm[2]),
  R = as.vector(img[,,1]),
  G = as.vector(img[,,2]),
  B = as.vector(img[,,3])
)


library(ggplot2)

plotTheme <- function() {
  theme(
panel.background = element_rect(
  size = 3,
  colour = "black",
  fill = "white"),
axis.ticks = element_line(
  size = 2),
panel.grid.major = element_line(
  colour = "gray80",
  linetype = "dotted"),
panel.grid.minor = element_line(
  colour = "gray90",
  linetype = "dashed"),
axis.title.x = element_text(
  size = rel(1.2),
  face = "bold"),
axis.title.y = element_text(
  size = rel(1.2),
  face = "bold"),
plot.title = element_text(
  size = 20,
  face = "bold",
  vjust = 1.5)
  )
}

ggplot(data = imgRGB, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(colour = rgb(imgRGB[c("R", "G", "B")])) +labs(title = "Original Image: Tissue") +xlab("x") +ylab("y") +plotTheme()


kClusters <- 3
kMeans <- kmeans(imgRGB[, c("R", "G", "B")], centers = kClusters)
kColours <- rgb(kMeans$centers[kMeans$cluster,])

kColours[kColours=="#8B8B8B"]<-"#1874CD"
kColours[kColours=="#565656"]<-"#FFFFFF"
kColours[kColours=="#CCCCCC"]<-"#FFFFFF"
ggplot(data = imgRGB, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(colour = kColours) +labs(title = paste("k-Means Clustering of", kClusters, "Colours")) +xlab("x") +ylab("y") + plotTheme()
```

Image:

[image]

This is the image I have processed until now:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6aSE.jpg]

Comment: Please share some code and a reproducible example.

Comment: Please find the edit above n tell me if u need anything else

Comment: Consider importing data as a raster (see package `raster`). You will be able to draw shapes based on coordinates.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion any idea on how will i get specific coordinates of only black pixels

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no white nor black pixels in your image?

Comment: Sorry I meant blue pixels . The image i get is updated in the post